# Add character to the left of the String

Tags: sql-server, database, string

Suppose, Table A has column "Name"

```
Name
====
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Now , I want to the table like this:-

```
Name
====
naaa
nbbb
nccc
```

It is very silly but I am asking what is the simplest string function to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use string concatenation. You can also use the [CONCAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) function in SQL Server 2012 onward

```
select
'n' + [Name]
From YourTable


select
CONCAT('n',[Name])
From YourTable
```

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570000/john-cappelletti) pointed out, you may want to update your table...

```
update YourTable
set [Name] = 'n' + [Name]
```

Comment: The fun thing about your update is that if you keep running it, it will keep adding `n` to the front :)

Answer (score 4):

The following adds an 'n' to all entries not starting with an 'n' already.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Name = 'n' + Name 
WHERE Name NOT LIKE 'n%'
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote here, it's a valid answer.

Comment: what if i want to put 'n' to all names ?

Comment: Then you remove the `WHERE` clause. The downside of that is that the script would be rendered useless when executed more than once, because you'll add more n's than you might want to.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer:

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET Name = CONCAT( 'n', Name);
```

Comment: That looks like the upvoted answer that is more than a year old - if you want to back it, vote it up. If you want to append something, add some more explanation to your answer